# SO showing wrong User Name

Tags: bug, top-bar

My name is Vikas V with 841 reputation as on 16th June on SO. As can be seen in the screen shot, my rep is 1 and my welcome name is user2488578. Is this a possible bug?

[image: SO]

Comment: Weird...are you on a shared computer by any chance? Did you try logging out and back in again?

Comment: Are you logged in from your own account?

Comment: Go to your profile page and click "my logins", to the left of "network profile" link. What do you see?

Comment: If I log out and login back, it shows correct data..

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again, huh? @Bart

Comment: @VikasV Cache is always the culprit. Though it shouldn't in this case.

Comment: @hjpotter92 haha, sorta. I'm assuming either someone else did not log off, or the OP did not log in correctly, creating another account.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd 
My Logins
Log in or sign up on any Stack Exchange site using these accounts

×
 Stack Exchange
ugetvikasv@gmail.com (used yesterday)
change password  remove
add more logins…

Comment: Didn't ask to see your actual email, just if you see logins and how many. Well, nothing out of the ordinary there.

Comment: Another idea: did you by any chance visit http://facebook.stackoverflow.com and logged in there?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't visit facebook.stackoverflow.com and logged in there..

Comment: OK, out of ideas. One last question, is this still happening now? Can you reproduce this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I logged out.. cleared my cache and logged in back. I can't reproduce now..

Comment: So probably [meta-tag:status-norepro], temporary hickup. Unless of course this will happen again. :)

Comment: darn cache invalidation - apparently it strikes again...

Comment: why are you using IE .. i mean no developer use IE ... and i am sure you are not NO DEVELOPER

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Am not a fan of IE and don't use it. But, check my developed websites on IE as some people still use it. So, accidently I had to browse SO on IE.